# dumpe2fs prints the same magic number = 0xEF53 for ext2, ext3, ext4 file systems. Is it correct?

Tags: filesystem

I created 3 partitions with file systems ext2, ext3, ext4.
For each partition dumpe2fs prints the same magic number: 0xEF53
Is it correct?